# Detect invalid URL parameters using Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, url, parameters

Is there a good way within the Spring framework to detect when an incoming URL has an invalid parameter? It seems like the default behavior is to ignore unrecognized parameters. The best solution I can find involves adding a parameter mapping to all my endpoints and check that mapping against the parameters it is expecting.

For example, say I have a widget site with a collection endpoint.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/widgets", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<WidgetList> getWidgets(
        @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search) {
    // ...
    // Get list of widgets
    // ...
    return new ResponseEntity<WidgetList>(widgetList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The "search" parameter is optional because leaving it out is a convenience allowing all widgets to be found. I support a search syntax such that the following finds widgets where the foo attribute has a value of bar

```
GET https://example.com/widgets?search=foo:bar
```

A user makes a typo

```
GET https://example.com/widgets?saerch=foo:bar
```

This fails silently. Instead of finding widgets where foo=bar, all are found. I'd like it to return a 400 error stating that the "saerch" parameter is not supported. A great answer would be some sort of strict option on RequestMapping, like the following.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/widgets", method = RequestMethod.GET, paramsStrict = true)
public ResponseEntity<WidgetList> getWidgets(
        @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search) {
    // ...
    // Get list of widgets
    // ...
    return new ResponseEntity<WidgetList>(widgetList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

As far as I know such doesn't exist. I haven't figured out a clean way to intercept the request and check for all methods (and somehow communicate which parameters are valid for each method). The best I've figured out so far is to add a parameter map and check the map against accepted parameters in every single controller method.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/widgets", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<WidgetList> getWidgets(
        @RequestParam(value = "search", required = false) String search, 
        @RequestParam Map<String, String> allRequestParams) {
    validateParameters(allRequestParms);
    // ...
    // Get list of widgets
    // ...
    return new ResponseEntity<WidgetList>(widgetList, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Please don't post answers about my design or how I could make the search parameter required. That's beside the point I'm trying to make with a simple example. In my real-world application there are well-designed cases where checking for invalid parameter names would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own [Servlet Filter](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html) or [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) to validate parameters.

Following example with Filter:

```
public class ParametersValidationFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (validateParameters((HttpServletRequest)request, (HttpServletResponse)response)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    private boolean validateParameters(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // Check parameter names in request.getParameterNames()
        /*
        Invalid parameter yields response.setStatus(HttpServletReponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST)
        and additional info in response body
        */

        // Otherwise, validation succeeds:
        return true;
    }

    /* Other methods */
}
```

Also, Filter can be configurated with init method.

This 'filter-or-interceptor' way is better due to ability to reuse as well SOLID at all.